Visual Studio Setup project prerequisite include and install - wrong runtime exe created in temp
I use Setup project.
In project properties I tick two runtime version which I want to be included. I select the download from the vendors website, save.
Then build.
When start Setup.exe on other computer (which does not have the runtimes), it offers correctly the two runtimes to be installed but they wont be installed.
Cause:
In temp folder there are the two installers created with correct name, eg.: windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.33-win-x64.exe but the content of the file is incorrect.The real installer (which can be downloaded from MS manually) is about 55 MB but the generated in the temp is just 1.5 MB.
My installer do not say anything just step over continouing with the MSI.
If I start the runtime installer from temp manually it says: .NET 4.7.2 is already installed on your computer (but I wanted just a desktop runtime, which can (and must) be installed if I download it manually.
I want the installer to check and install the correct runtime if necessary. It creates installers int temp with correct name but incorrect content.
Why does it do this and how to solve?

And of course, the app can not be run untill I download and install that runtime on that computer where I test it.
